# MongoDB Aggregate Slow Performance When Using Sort

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection (tvshow episodes) with more than 1,200,000 document,

here is my schema :

```
  var episodeSchema = new Schema({
    imdbId: { type : String },
    showId: {type : String},
    episodeId: { type : String },
    episodeIdNumber:{ type : Number },
    episodeTitle:{ type : String },
    showTitle:{type : String},
    seasonNumber:{type : Number},
    episodeNumber:{type : Number},
    airDate : {type : String},
    summary:{type : String}
});
```

I created Index for `episodeTitle` `episodeIdNumber` `seasonNumber` `episodeNumber` `episodeId` and `showId`

Now i used mongodb aggregate group to get every tvshow episodes

here is the aggregate query i used :

```
episode.aggregate( [
            { $match : { showId : "scorpion" } },
            {$sort:{"episodeNumber":-1}},
            { $group: {

            _id: "$seasonNumber", count: { $sum: 1 } ,
            episodes : { $push:  { episodeId : "$episodeId" , episodeTitle: "$episodeTitle" , episodeNumber: "$episodeNumber" , seasonNumber: "$seasonNumber" , airDate: "$airDate"  } }

            } }
            ,
            { $sort : { _id : -1  } }
] )
```

Now when i am run this query its take more than `2605.907 ms` , after some digging i found out why its slow , it was because of using `{$sort:{"episodeNumber":-1}}` , without using `{$sort:{"episodeNumber":-1}}` its take around `19.178 ms` to run.

As i mentioned above i create an index for `episodeNumber` field and based on [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#pipeline-sequence-optimization) 
i used `sort` after `match` so basically everything was ok , and i didn't anything wrong.

So after this i thought something wrong with my indexes , so i removed `episodeNumber` index and  reindexd , but i had same time nothing changed.

At end one time i tried run aggregate group query without `episodeNumber` indexed and surprisingly it was faster ! its take around `20.118 ms` .

I wants know why this happened , isn't indexes to get faster query ?

**Update**

query explain output :

```
{
        "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
        "stages" : [
            {
                "$cursor" : {
                    "query" : {
                        "showId" : "scorpion"
                    },
                    "sort" : {
                        "episodeNumber" : -1
                    },
                    "fields" : {
                        "airDate" : 1,
                        "episodeId" : 1,
                        "episodeNumber" : 1,
                        "episodeTitle" : 1,
                        "seasonNumber" : 1,
                        "_id" : 0
                    },
                    "queryPlanner" : {
                        "plannerVersion" : 1,
                        "namespace" : "test.episodes",
                        "indexFilterSet" : false,
                        "parsedQuery" : {
                            "showId" : {
                                "$eq" : "scorpion"
                            }
                        },
                        "winningPlan" : {
                            "stage" : "EOF"
                        },
                        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group" : {
                    "_id" : "$seasonNumber",
                    "count" : {
                        "$sum" : {
                            "$const" : 1
                        }
                    },
                    "episodes" : {
                        "$push" : {
                            "episodeId" : "$episodeId",
                            "episodeTitle" : "$episodeTitle",
                            "episodeNumber" : "$episodeNumber",
                            "seasonNumber" : "$seasonNumber",
                            "airDate" : "$airDate"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$sort" : {
                    "sortKey" : {
                        "_id" : -1
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `showId`?

Comment: as @dgiugg said, you need to have an index on your match query first, so an index on showId, episodenumber will maximize your query performance.

Comment: @Tiramisu Yes but suppose he does not have an index on `showId`. Why would the query be faster without the index on `episodeNumber`? I mean, a wrong index would just be discarded and should not slow the query, compared to no index at all.

Comment: Ok the answer to my question is yes, as you said at the beginning of the post. Sorry. For each query try to do `.explain()` to see which indexes it uses. It seems that using `showId` index is faster thant using `episodeNumber` index, and this is the answer to your question. But in this case why does Mongo use the slower one when it has the choice?

Comment: @dgiugg i updated question , and about your first question , yes i indexed `showId` too.

Comment: @dgiugg my point was that he needs a compound index on showId AND episodeNumber. I don't know why the query ran faster without an index on either episodeNumber or showId.